# Accessing a derived class members from an "interface" in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface

I'm working on a UI framework and trying to make my code more manageable and using interfaces(I know they're just classes.) seems to be the best option.

I'll give you an example of what i want to do:

In the Control base class it will have the general members that all controls will have such as ID,name and location. I want to be able to implement an interface that will manage the text of say a button. The interface will store and draw the text. 
Now to do this i will need to override the Draw() function however i don't know how i forward declare that.

Psudo code

```
class ITextAble
virtual void DrawText() override Control::Draw()
{
    Control::Draw();
    GetRenderWindow()->draw(m_text);
}

class Button : public ITextAble

virtual void Draw ()
{
    m_renderWindow->draw(m_shape);
}
sf::RenderWindow * GetRenderWindow () const
{
    return m_renderWindow;
}
```

If you can't tell already I'm pretty new to C++ programming, i have no idea if this is even possible to do in C++ but if true I'm going to be amazed yet again.

Comment: only `Draw` can override `Draw`. The overridden `Draw` will have to settle for calling `DrawText`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better use some ready lib like fltk, wxWidgets, QT, MFC, GTKMM etc. 
You will find creating a GUI lib a super complex task.

Looks like you don't understand the interface (pure virtual class) concept. Such a class must not have any members - only pure virtual methods. Otherwise - this is an abstract class.

Read Scott Meyers: Effective C++

Something which can cover your concept using classic dynamic polymorphism version:

WARN! THIS IS BAD DESIGN !!!

Better way - is without sf::RenderWindow * GetRenderWindow () const function at all.

```
// a pure virtual class - interface
class IControl {
IControl(const IControl&) = delete;
IControl& operator=(const IControl&) = delete;
protected:
  constexpr IControl() noexcept
  {}
protected:
  virtual sf::RenderWindow * GetRenderWindow() const = 0; 
public:
  virtual ~IControl() noexcept
  {}
}

// an abstract class
class ITextAble:public IControl {
  ITextAble(const ITextAble&) = delete;
  ITextAble& operator=(const ITextAble&) = delete;
protected:
   ITextAble(const std::string& caption):
     IControl(),
     caption_(caption)
  {} 
   void DrawText();
public:
   virtual ~ITextAble() noexcept = 0;
private:
   std::string caption_;
};

// in .cpp file

void ITextAble::DrawText()
{
  this->GetRenderWindow()->draw(caption_.data());
}

ITextAble::~ITextAble() noexcept
{}

// 
class Button :public ITextAble
{
public:
  Button(int w, int h, const char* caption) :
    ITextAble(caption),
    window_(new sf::RenderWindow(w,h) ),
  {}
  void show() {
     this->DrawText();
  }
  virtual ~Button() noexecept override
  {}
protected:
  virtual sf::RenderWindow* GetRenderWindow() const override {
    return window_;
  }
private:
  sf::RenderWindow* window_;
};

// pointer on reference
Button *btn = new Button(120, 60, "Click me");
btn->show();
```

Comment: I figured as much, I've known of a another way that is to reference the control in the ITextAble constructor. Thanks for explaining the pure virtual class concept. 

But i will not use GUI libraries as I'm confident I'll be able to manage. I know it's hard, that's why i want to do it. 

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Abstract classes can't be instantiated themselves, but can also have non virtual functions and member variables.